# Efficient way to read/store multiple objects in Riak Python Client?

Tags: python, riak

I'm writing a restore riak database tool, and I need to write hundreds of thousands of keys from one riak server to another. Doing so for about 91,000 keys takes 11 minutes (not efficient at all). The basic outline of my code is as follows:

```
data_objects = bucket.multiget(keys)
for data_object in data_objects:
    newEntry = bucket.new(data_object.key, data=data_object.data)
    newEntry.store()
```

The python app spends about 7 minutes in the single multiget() function call which creates the data_objects list of 91,000 Riak Objects, and it takes about four minutes in the 91,000 calls to the store() function.

Is there a more efficient way to do read the objects? A more efficient way to store the objects? There is a multiget function in the riak python library, but not a multistore function.

Comment: isn't the replication of riak takes care of restoration in case of failure ?Just curious as to what is the purpose of the tool

Comment: yes but i need to also be able to filter the backup by specific buckets/indexes which wouldn't be possible if i copied the entire riak database

Comment: Now i get what you are trying to do. Just wondering, what is the percentage of data subset that is valid/one you are interested to the total data

Comment: side question though, would replicating riak entail copying the contents of the directory in /usr/local/var/lib/riak/leveldb (or somewhere similar)?

Comment: for any given backup, probably 20% of the data would be of interest

Comment: Are you using HTTP or Protocol Buffers? I wonder if there is any noticeable difference in the performance. And maybe a stupid question, but the servers do not belong to the same cluster, do they?

Comment: When reading from riak, I use the "pbc" protocol and when writing to riak, I use the "http" protocol.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use multiget, create your own threads, share keys to them equally, get from old bucket, store to new one.  gevent.monkey_patch.all() may help too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: May be not detailed or good enough but my answer definitely purposes a "more efficient way" for the problem. The multiget method of  riak client uses same python threads to speedup bulk reads, so instead of waiting for the completion of the whole multiget operation, read and write could be done in our own threads. 
gevent can be used, because this is an IO bound operation where the async workers are the most appropriate choice for boosting the performance.